# Cython's Extension module's class's methods not visible/give a name Error when mentioned

Tags: python, cython

I tried to make a modified list class for Python based on a project I'm working on and decided to try to speed it up with Cython

On my first go, most of the class's functions (except for the special functions) weren't visible and couldn't be accessed

I've tried to bounce around the names from cdef, cpdef, and def for the methods and class declarations both and tried googling to see if I have the correct syntax as well as to see if someone else has had a similar problem

Here is my Code:

```
class list_2:

        cpdef append(self , object item):
            self._lst = array(self + [item])

        cpdef pop(self,int index = -1):
            temp_lst = array(range(len(self) -1 ))

            if index > len(self)-1 and index >= 0 or index*(-1) > len(len) and index < 0:
                raise IndexError
            else:
                if index <0:
                    index = index*(-1)-1
                for x in range(len(self)):
                    if x!= index:
                        temp_lst[i] = self[x]
                        i+=1
                self._lst = temp_lst
```

Comment: It looks like you declared your class as `class list_2`. You should declare it is as a `cdef class list_2` instead in order for it to be a cython extension type. Otherwise, cython treats it as a regular python class. [This link](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cdef_classes.html) in the documentation might be helpful for learning about cython classes.

Comment: Also, I am not sure if trying to re-implement a list class will necessarily bring you the performance benefits you expect. If your data is all of a single type, you might also want to consider using cython's typed memoryviews or working with C arrays and pointers instead. It might be helpful to know why you are interested in making a modified list class.

Comment: @CodeSurgeon well, as I think I mentioned, I've tried `cdef`, `cpdef`, and `def` for the class declarations and all of them have given me the same result of not having those functions included with the class
Honestly, I'm just trying to make this class for practice in Cython and Python
Any other advice that you might have would be most appreciated

Comment: Did you also write a `.pxd` file (basically the equivalent of a c header file) as well for your `.pyx` file? If so, add that to the question. Are you getting an error when compiling your cython code or when running it? Can you show us those as well? What imports are you using for the array class?

Comment: @CodeSurgeon well, it's actually when I import the Python code and try to access the list_2's append attribute which causes the NameError, which is the issue of how it's not usable or visible
No, I don't know how to write a `.pxd` file, I guess I didn't come across that yet

Comment: For this kind of question it's very helpful to actually include the error message in the question, rather than posting a vague summary of it 6 comments down. Fortunately you've been given a good answer without it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple example to help you get started with cython classes. First, I create my `setup.py` file, which I use to compile my cython `.pyx` file by calling `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`.

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from distutils.core import Extension

extensions = [
    Extension("mylist", sources=["mylist.pyx"], libraries=[], extra_compile_args=["-w"]),
]
setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize(extensions)
)
```

Next, I would write up a `.pxd` file. Like I mentioned in the comments, this is basically a header file that defines all of the "c-side" class properties and methods that you want to access that were defined with `cdef` or `cpdef`. An example `mylist.pxd` would look like this:

```
cdef class MyList:
    cdef public list _base_list
    cpdef append(self, object item)
    cpdef pop(self, int index=*)#Note: * is used in place of default values
    cpdef get_data(self)
```

Now we are ready to create our `mylist.pyx` file that actually does the work. To keep things simple, I will implement our cython list using python lists (which is pretty nonsensical performance-wise but will avoid the need to delve into arrays, which are a little trickier). The code might look like this:

```
cdef class MyList:

    def __cinit__(self):#__cinit__ is preferred for cdef class constructors
        self._base_list = []

    cpdef append(self, object item):
        self._base_list = self._base_list + [item]

    cpdef pop(self, int index=-1):
        self._base_list.pop(index)

    cpdef get_data(self):
        return self._base_list
```

Once this is all compiled, you can use this silly `MyList` class in python. Here is `MyList` in action in a `main.py` file:

```
from mylist import MyList

a = MyList()
a.append("apple")
a.append("banana")
a.append("tomato")
a.append("pear")
a.pop(2)#one of these fruit is not like the others...
print a.get_data()
```

Let me know if you are having issues compiling or running this example. I tested this on my laptop using Python 2.7 and the latest Cython master (version 0.26b0).

Comment: Thanks! I looked at your examples and I got it working! :)
One more question tho. Some people downvoted my post, can you tell me what is wrong/what can I do to improve it? Thanks again!

Comment: @Ali Abbas I personally did not downvote, the biggest thing to improve would have been to add the exact error message to your question. Otherwise we can all only guess what is wrong! Also, given that you are trying to speed up code with cython, reimplementing python's list class will not help do that. Typing cdef variables with `list`, `object`, `dict`, etc does not help much as those containers can hold literally any object, so no real type information can be inferred. Also, cython's documentation is great and likely would have cleared up your confusion about cdef, cpdef, and def.

Comment: Thanks for the feed back

Comment: @CodeSurgeon this is genius.  Thank you!